# Unable to recreate deleted channel

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Using graph API, I am unable to recreate the deleted channel.

Using Microsoft Team windows client, I have deleted a channel. Then, I tried to recreate with the same name and that seems working. But when I tried the same scenario using graph API, I get "Channel name already existed" error.

#### Example

#### Delete API:

`DELETE https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/<groupid>/channels/<ABCchannelid>`

#### Create API:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/<groupid>/channels
{
  "displayName": "ABC",
  "description": "desc"
}
```

Response

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Channel name already existed, please use other name",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "guid",
      "date": "2019-12-19T09:01:40"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you "Delete" a Channel or a Team, it's not immediately permanently deleted, it goes into a "temporary" deleted state so that it can be restored if it was deleted by accident. This means you can:

1. [Restore the channel](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/uclobby/2018/08/21/restore-deleted-teams-and-channels-from-microsoft-teams/), if you want it back as it was
2. "Recreate" the Channel, if you really don't want the original one, but using a roundabout way - you need to Restore the channel as above, then rename it to a useless name (e.g. "asdfgh" or whatever), THEN delete it, and you can then create a new channel with the original desired name. There's more on this approach [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams/recreating-channel-with-same-name-after-deleting-it/m-p/120007).

Obviously (1) is the easiest, if you just want the channel back.

Please don't forget to mark this as the correct answer if it helps you.

Comment: Yes, I see that is a way to restore channel but not finding graph api to do this.

Comment: I'm not sure whether it's possible on the Graph to restore, but is this something you want to do regularly, or just once-off to fix a problem? If it's just once-off, use the UI to do the restore rather

Comment: Thanks. But restore from UI is not an option for us. Each Teams is following defined template. So from background we are making sure all our Teams are following template. if any deleted channel recreating/restoring them.

Comment: ohh, I see, so this wasn't a once-off accidental delete, now I understand. I'm not sure that it's possible to "restore" via Graph, but perhaps it is and someone else can help.

Answer (score 0):

@vasanth TT - When any channel is deleted, Teams holds the data for several weeks in order to allow Team Owner to recover the deleted channel. During that time one can not create new channel with the same name within the same team. You can create channel with the same name in different team but not in the same team where it was previously created

Comment: I should be fine with restoring deleted channels, but not finding a way to do it programmatically, no supported graph api.